# Using bash script to remove from sentence words longer than [x] characters

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a sentence (array) and I would like to remove from it all words longer than 8 characters.

Example sentence:

```bash
var="one two three four giberish-giberish five giberish-giberish six"
```

I would like to get:

```bash
var="one two three four five six"
```

So far I'm using this:

````bash
echo $var | tr ' ' '\n' | awk 'length($1) <= 6 { print $1 }' | tr '\n ' ' ' ```
Solution above works fine but as you can see I'm replacing space with newline then filtering words and then replacing back newline with space.

I'm pretty sure there must be better and more "elegant" solution without swapping space/newline.
````

Comment: `awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS=" "} length($0) <= 6' <<< "$var"`

Comment: Regarding `I have a sentence (array)` - the sample input you provided is a string, not an array. If you want help with an array, show an array otherwise you'll get answers to some other problem than the one you really have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pure Bash, you can filter into a new array the words less than some chosen length:

```
#!/bin/bash

var="one two three four giberish-giberish five giberish-giberish six" 

new_arr=()
for w in $var; do  # no quotes on purpose to split string
    [[ ${#w} -lt 6 ]] && new_arr+=( "$w" )
done    

declare -p new_arr
# declare -a new_arr=([0]="one" [1]="two" [2]="three" [3]="four" [4]="five" [5]="six")
```

Or if the source is already an array:

```
old_arr=(one two three four giberish-giberish five giberish-giberish six)
new_arr=()
for w in ${old_arr[@]}; do 
    [[ ${#w} -lt 6 ]] && new_arr+=( "$w" )
done
```

You may want to delete the words in `old_arr` as you loop over it. If you know that each `$w` is unique, you can do:

```
old_arr=(one two three four giberish-giberish five giberish-giberish six)
for w in ${old_arr[@]}; do 
    [[ ${#w} -ge 6 ]] && old_arr=("${old_arr[@]/$w}")
done
```

But this has two issues: 1) If you have equal prefixes, all will be deleted and 2) The existing indices will remain:

```
$ declare -p old_arr
declare -a old_arr=([0]="one" [1]="two" [2]="three" [3]="four" [4]="" [5]="five" [6]="" [7]="six")
```

You could also `unset` the offending item by keeping a separate index:

```
old_arr=(one two three four giberish-giberish five giberish-giberish six)
idx=0
for w in ${old_arr[@]}; do 
    [[ ${#w} -ge 6 ]] && unset 'old_arr[idx]'
    (( idx++ ))
done
```

But then you end up with discontinuous array indexes (but the existing qualifying words remain at the same index):

```
$ declare -p old_arr
declare -a old_arr=([0]="one" [1]="two" [2]="three" [3]="four" [5]="five" [7]="six")
```

It *usually* better to filter into a new array unless you want to keep the existing indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

```sh
arr=(one two three four giberish-giberish five giberish-giberish six)
for var in "${arr[@]}"; do (( ${#var} > 8 )) || echo -n "$var "; done
echo # for that newline in the end
```

And another:

```sh
awk '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if(length($i) < 8) printf "%s ", $i } print "" # for that newline in the end }'
```

And a third!

```sh
awk -v RS='[[:space:]]+' 'length < 8 { v=v" "$0 }; END{print substr(v, 2)}'
```

The last one prints a "perfect" single-space delimited string with no extra leading or trailing whitespace.

Comment: This one adds newlines after each word. I would like to have space there not newline.

Comment: Amended my answer to match requirements

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```sh
#!/bin/bash
var="one two three four giberish-giberish five giberish-giberish six"
awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS=" "} length($0) <= 6' <<< "$var"
# -> one two three four five six
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/RVw3RT).

The `BEGIN{RS=ORS=" "}` sets the record input/output separator to a space and `length($0) <= 6` only keeps the fields that are equal or shorter than 6 chars.

You can also consider the workarounds with GNU `sed` and `perl`:

```sh
sed -E 's/\s*\S{7,}//g' <<< "$var"
perl -pe 's/\s*\S{7,}//g' <<< "$var"
```

See [this online demo](https://ideone.com/OtjL6X).

A non-GNU sed workaround could look like

```sh
sed 's/[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]\{7,\}//g' <<< "$var"
```

Here, all occurrences of zero or more whitespace (`\s*`, `[[:space:]]*`) followed with seven or more non-whitespace chars (`\S{7,}`, `[^[:space:]]\{7,\}`) are removed.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed 's/\<[a-z-]\{8,\}\> //g' file
var="one two three four five six"
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
<<<"$var" sed -E 'y/ /\n/;s/..{8}.*\n//mg;y/\n/ /'
```

Translate spaces to newlines.

Remove all lines that are more than 8 characters long.

Translate newlines to spaces.